# Create documents with dynamic height with borb

Tags: python, pdf, borb

I think `borb` is pretty amazing for generating PDFs with `Python`.

I'd love to use `borb` to create documents to print on a thermal printer (fixed width, endless height of document). The documents have messages of different length thus the height of the document would need to be adjusted every time (so no blank space gets printed after the message).

Is there a way to determine the size/height of the content and to resize the page accordingly in borb?

Answer (score 1):

disclaimer: I am the author of `borb`.

The PDF specification explicitly states a maximum page width/height. So from that point of view, you will not be able to go above those limits.

Now to answer your other question, you can determine the width and height of a piece of content in `borb` by adding it to a (dummy) `Page`.

```py
def get_layout_box(p: Paragraph) -> Rectangle:
    pg: Page = Page()
    ZERO: Decimal = Decimal(0)
    W: Decimal = Decimal(1000)   # max width you would allow
    H: Decimal = Decimal(1000)   # max height you would allow
    return p.layout(pg, Rectangle(ZERO, ZERO, W, H))
```